# What's wrong with this simple python code?

Tags: python, error-handling

```
n = int(raw_input())
s = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
ar = index = [0]*n; done = [False]*n
for a in range(n): ar[a] = int(s[a])
k=0
for a in range(5):
     m = 1000000001
     for i in range(n):
         if done[i]: continue
         if ar[i] < m: m = ar[i]
     if m == 1000000001: 
         sys.stdout.write('-1\n')
         break
     #print m
     for i in range(n):
         if ar[i] == m:
             index[k] = i
             k+=1
             done[i]=True

print index
```

The algorithm is quite simple. **ar** is an array of **n** (>= 5) integers. I intend to store the 0 based positions of the first 5 smallest integers of the array in **index**.

After taking **n** as input, **n** space separated integers are inputted on the next line.

The problem is very weird - for the following input:

```
7
6 17 5 3 13 8 10
```

when I uncomment `#print m` in the code, it prints `3 3 0 3 0` (expected output is `3 5 6 8 10`); also, an `IndexError` occurs (that is just a symptom of the real problem).

Variable **done** is working as expected (it contains a list of boolean values, where, if `done[i]` is `True`, then `ar[i]` should not be taken into consideration while looking for `min(ar)`

I did a lot of debugging by printing values of variables at different locations, but couldn't reason out anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really following your code, but this:

```
ar = index = [0]*n
```

seems quite strange to do in python, try to replace it with:

```
ar = [0]*n
index = [0]*n
```

And see if it works.

This example, may help to see why that seems strange:

```
>>> a = b = [0] * 5
>>> a
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> b
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> a[1] = 2
>>> a
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
>>> b
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

You may be interested in taking a loook at [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables).

**Side note:**

Try to make your code more readable:

- go to a new line when required, there's no actual need for `;`
- don't write for-loops/if-statements in one line: there's list comprehension for that.

Also (if I understood what you're trying to do), your code could be rewritten like:

```
s = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
ar = [(int(num),i) for i,num in enumerate(s)]
ar.sort()
print [a[1] for a in ar[:5]]
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked! I didn't know that by writing a = b = [], python simply refers to the same list with a,b

Comment: @Rushil: Python objects are always passed by reference, never by value. "a = b = []" is the same as "b = []; a = b", so you end up with both variables pointing to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

`ar = index = [0]*n` should be `ar = [0] * n; index = [5] * 5`. 
The way you wrote it, ar and index *are the **same** list*.

Somewhat more pythonic would be

```
from heapq import nsmallest
s = map(int, raw_input().split())
print [ind for value, ind in nsmallest(5, enumerate(s), key=lambda x: x[1])]
```

which gives `[3, 5, 6, 8, 10]` for your input (no need to give n explicitly).

Comment: thanks for shortening the code. And by the way, index = [5]*5 won't work. size of index should be at least n (in case integers in ar[] repeat themselves)

Comment: @Rushil: Ah, that explains that :-) You have repetitions, and want to store *all* positions of the 5 smallest integers. In that case my answer gives other output than yours.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have a lot less trouble if you learn and use the higher level powerful features python provides. Less code is easier to understand and debug:

```
>>> s=[6,17,5,3,13,8,10]
>>> d=dict(enumerate(s))
>>> sd=sorted(d, cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(d[x], d[y]))
>>> [d[sd[v]] for v in range(5)]
[3, 5, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: thanks for that. I had just converted a C code snippet to python, to see how it works :-)